# Parallel download using Curl command line utility

Tags: linux, shell, unix, curl

I want to download some pages from a website and I did it successfully using `curl` but I was wondering if somehow `curl` downloads multiple pages at a time just like most of the download managers do, it will speed up things a little bit. Is it possible to do it in `curl` command line utility?

The current command I am using is

```
curl 'http://www...../?page=[1-10]' 2>&1 > 1.html
```

Here I am downloading pages from 1 to 10 and storing them in a file named `1.html`.

Also, is it possible for `curl` to write output of each URL to separate file say `URL.html`, where `URL` is the actual URL of the page under process.

Comment: pre-request to find out the content-length, use `--range` to splice the single to multiple downloads, run multi-process curl, maintain order of chunks and join them as soon you've got am orderly sequence, it is what most developers are doing (for example: [htcat project](https://github.com/eladkarako/htcat))

Comment: How do you know how many pages to download? Are you just arbitrarily selecting 1 to 10?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9865866/1072112 ... though it geared towards file downloads, the explanation of curl usage in the selected answer may be useful.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, `curl` is just a simple UNIX process. You can have as many of these `curl` processes running in parallel and sending their outputs to different files.

`curl` can use the filename part of the URL to generate the local file. Just use the `-O` option (`man curl` for details).

You could use something like the following

```
urls="http://example.com/?page1.html http://example.com?page2.html" # add more URLs here

for url in $urls; do
   # run the curl job in the background so we can start another job
   # and disable the progress bar (-s)
   echo "fetching $url"
   curl $url -O -s &
done
wait #wait for all background jobs to terminate
```

Comment: let say I have to download 100 pages... your script will start 100 curl instances simultaneously(might choke the network)... can we do something like at any given point of time, only X instances of `curl` are running and as soon as one of them finishes its job, the script launch another instance... some sort of `Job Scheduling`??

Comment: Ravi.. this gets more difficult. You need a job queue served by multiple processes. One simple solution would be to send all jobs to the UNIX `batch` command (try `man batch`). It executes jobs when the system load is below a certain threshold. So most jobs would be queued and only a few will be running at a time.

Comment: @EladKarako: note the `&` at the end of the `curl` command. This runs the `curl` job in the background without blocking the main process. So yes, this is definitely parallel (although I still prefer the `make` trick or even parallel `xargs`)

Comment: GNU [`parallel`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/moreutils/parallel.1.en.html) can limit the number of "jobslots". ([examples](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/5914e02df62137e47f32))

Answer (score 57):

My answer is a bit late, but I believe all of the existing answers fall just a little short.  The way I do things like this is with `xargs`, which is capable of running a specified number of commands in subprocesses.

The one-liner I would use is, simply:

```
$ seq 1 10 | xargs -n1 -P2 bash -c 'i=$0; url="http://example.com/?page${i}.html"; curl -O -s $url'
```

This warrants some explanation.  The use of `-n 1` instructs `xargs` to process a single input argument at a time.  In this example, the numbers `1 ... 10` are each processed separately.  And `-P 2` tells `xargs` to keep 2 subprocesses running all the time, each one handling a single argument, until all of the input arguments have been processed.

You can think of this as MapReduce in the shell.  Or perhaps just the Map phase.  Regardless, it's an effective way to get a lot of work done while ensuring that you don't fork bomb your machine.  It's possible to do something similar in a for loop in a shell, but end up doing process management, which starts to seem pretty pointless once you realize how insanely great this use of `xargs` is.

Update: I suspect that my example with `xargs` could be improved (at least on Mac OS X and BSD with the `-J` flag).  With GNU Parallel, the command is a bit less unwieldy as well:

```
parallel --jobs 2 curl -O -s http://example.com/?page{}.html ::: {1..10}
```

Comment: Also note that if you have a full-featured version of xargs, you can simply do the following: `seq 1 10 | xargs -I{} -P2 -- curl -O -s 'http://example.com/?page{}.html'`

Comment: plus one because the use of xargs is **brilliant**.

Answer (score 24):

As of 7.66.0, the `curl` utility finally has built-in support for parallel downloads of multiple URLs within a single non-blocking process, which should be much faster and more resource-efficient compared to `xargs` and background spawning, in most cases:

```
curl -Z 'http://httpbin.org/anything/[1-9].{txt,html}' -o '#1.#2'
```

This will download 18 links in parallel and write them out to 18 different files, also in parallel. The official announcement of this feature from Daniel Stenberg is here: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/07/22/curl-goez-parallel/

Comment: To limit the number of concurrent download, one can use the `--parallel-max [num]` flag.

Comment: How to provide a list of urls from the file and write http status code (only) to the list of files (or one file)?

Answer (score 10):

Starting from `7.68.0` curl can fetch several urls in parallel. This example will fetch urls from `urls.txt` file with 3 parallel connections:

```
curl --parallel --parallel-immediate --parallel-max 3 --config urls.txt
```

urls.txt:

```
url = "example1.com"
output = "example1.html"
url = "example2.com"
output = "example2.html"
url = "example3.com"
output = "example3.html"
url = "example4.com"
output = "example4.html"
url = "example5.com"
output = "example5.html"
```

Answer (score 8):

`curl` and `wget` cannot download a single file in parallel chunks, but there are alternatives:

- [**aria2**](https://aria2.github.io/) (written in C++, available in Deb and Cygwin repo's)

  ```
  aria2c -x 5 <url>
  ```
- [**axel**](https://github.com/axel-download-accelerator/axel) (written in C, available in Deb repo)

  ```
  axel -n 5 <url>
  ```
- [**wget2**](https://github.com/rockdaboot/wget2) (written in C, available in Deb repo)

  ```
  wget2 --max-threads=5 <url>
  ```
- [**lftp**](https://github.com/lavv17/lftp) (written in C++, available in Deb repo)

  ```
  lftp -n 5 <url>
  ```
- [**hget**](https://github.com/huydx/hget) (written in Go)

  ```
  hget -n 5 <url>
  ```
- [**pget**](https://github.com/Code-Hex/pget) (written in Go)

  ```
  pget -p 5 <url>
  ```

Comment: aria2 is also available as homebrew install.

Answer (score 6):

Curl can also accelerate a download of a file by splitting it into parts:

```
$ man curl |grep -A2 '\--range'
       -r/--range <range>
              (HTTP/FTP/SFTP/FILE)  Retrieve a byte range (i.e a partial docu-
              ment) from a HTTP/1.1, FTP or  SFTP  server  or  a  local  FILE.
```

Here is a script that will automatically launch curl with the desired number of concurrent processes:  https://github.com/axelabs/splitcurl

Answer (score 6):

For launching of parallel commands, why not use the venerable `make` command line utility.. It supports parallell execution and dependency tracking and whatnot.

How? In the directory where you are downloading the files, create a new file called `Makefile` with the following contents:

```
# which page numbers to fetch
numbers := $(shell seq 1 10)

# default target which depends on files 1.html .. 10.html
# (patsubst replaces % with %.html for each number)
all: $(patsubst %,%.html,$(numbers))

# the rule which tells how to generate a %.html dependency
# $@ is the target filename e.g. 1.html
%.html:
        curl -C - 'http://www...../?page='$(patsubst %.html,%,$@) -o $@.tmp
        mv $@.tmp $@
```

**NOTE** The last two lines should start with a TAB character (instead of 8 spaces) or make will not accept the file.

Now you just run:

```
make -k -j 5
```

The curl command I used will store the output in `1.html.tmp` and only if the curl command succeeds then it will be renamed to `1.html` (by the `mv` command on the next line). Thus if some download should fail, you can just re-run the same `make` command and it will resume/retry downloading the files that failed to download during the first time. Once all files have been successfully downloaded, make will report that there is nothing more to be done, so there is no harm in running it one extra time to be "safe".

(The `-k` switch tells make to keep downloading the rest of the files even if one single download should fail.)

Comment: "-j 5" tells make to run at most 5 curl commands in parallel.

Comment: Really the best solution since it allows resuming failed downloads and uses 'make' which is both robust and available on any unix system.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thoroughly explained and shows some nice features of make in the process

Comment: The only issue to use this method is I cannot really remember the `$(patsubst %,%.html,$(numbers))` part. This is way more hard than tar.

Answer (score 2):

Run a limited number of process is easy if your system have commands like `pidof` or `pgrep` which, given a process name, return the pids (the count of the pids tell how many are running).

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
max=4
running_curl() {
    set -- $(pidof curl)
    echo $#
}
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    while [ $(running_curl) -ge $max ] ; do
        sleep 1
    done
    curl "$1" --create-dirs -o "${1##*://}" &
    shift
done
```

to call like this:

```
script.sh $(for i in `seq 1 10`; do printf "http://example/%s.html " "$i"; done)
```

The curl line of the script is untested.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a solution based on `fmt` and `xargs`. The idea is to specify multiple URLs inside braces `http://example.com/page{1,2,3}.html` and run them in parallel with `xargs`. Following would start downloading in 3 process:

```
seq 1 50 | fmt -w40 | tr ' ' ',' \
| awk -v url="http://example.com/" '{print url "page{" $1 "}.html"}' \
| xargs -P3 -n1 curl -o
```

so 4 downloadable lines of URLs are generated and sent to `xargs`

```
curl -o http://example.com/page{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}.html
curl -o http://example.com/page{17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29}.html
curl -o http://example.com/page{30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42}.html
curl -o http://example.com/page{43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50}.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash 3 or above lets you populate an array with multiple values as it expands sequence expressions:

```
$ urls=( "" http://example.com?page={1..4} )
$ unset urls[0]
```

Note the `[0]` value, which was provided as shorthand to make the indices line up with page numbers, since bash arrays autonumber starting at zero. This strategy obviously might not always work. Anyway, you can unset it in this example.

Now you have a an array, and you can verify the contents with `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p urls
declare -a urls=([1]="http://example.com?Page=1" [2]="http://example.com?Page=2" [3]="http://example.com?Page=3" [4]="http://example.com?Page=4")
```

Now that you have a list of URLs in an array, expand the array into a curl command line:

```
$ curl $(for i in ${!urls[@]}; do echo "-o $i.html ${urls[$i]}"; done)
```

The `curl` command can take multiple URLs and fetch all of them, recycling the existing connection (HTTP/1.1) to a common server, but it needs the `-o` option before each one in order to download and save each target. Note that characters within some URLs may need to be escaped to avoid interacting with your shell.

Answer (score -5):

I am not sure about curl, but you can do that using [wget](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget).

```
wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains website.org \
     --no-parent \
         www.website.org/tutorials/html/
```

Comment: how to set the number of parallel downloads ?